# Function fallocate() & splice() from FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, splice

I needed to implement add and remove blocks in the middle of the large file - "hole punching" I can't find an analogue functions `fallocate()` and `splice()` under FreeBSD.

Comment: Unfortunately those functions don't exist within FreeBSD, and as noted on the man pages they are Linux only extensions.

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD has had [`posix_fallocate(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=posix_fallocate&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD%208.3-RELEASE) since 8.3 but no `splice()`.

Answer (score 1):

Roland is right about posix_fallocate(). BTW, I can not find fallocate() even on a Linux system here (RHEL-5.7), so you really don't want to rely on its presence even on Linux.

As for splice(), it would seem, no. The closest it comes to that on FreeBSD is sendfile() -- but only when the destination is a *socket*.